# Error: function declared as function returning function

Tags: c, linux, gnu, porting

I am porting a windows assembly to linux. I have certain code to port. I am actually a newbie with C in linux. I know C fundamentals are the same yet!

```
typedef struct sReader
{
    pReaderAddRef addRef;
    pReaderDelRef delRef;
}pReader, *pSReader;

typedef long (*pReaderAddRef)(struct sReader *);
typedef long (*pReaderDelRef)(struct sReader **);
```

The above code give me the error **'pReaderAddRef' declared as function returning a function**.

I understand the way callback functions work. But i dont really know how to resolve this error.

Kindly help.

Comment: you changed you question after getting an answer..

Comment: No it was a typo. I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't understand your original error message - I get

```
f.c:3:5: error: unknown type name ‘pReaderAddRef’
f.c:4:5: error: unknown type name ‘pReaderDelRef’
```

with your original code -

it seems you mixed up the order: in order to use the function pointers, you must have them defined.

```
struct sReader; // incomplete type, but ready to be used

//alternatively:
typedef struct sReader pReader, *pSReader; // taken from your edit, but these prefixes are misleading

typedef long (*pReaderAddRef)(struct sReader *); // or mytypename
typedef long (*pReaderDelRef)(struct sReader **);

struct sReader
{
    pReaderAddRef addRef; // Now you can use them
    pReaderDelRef delRef;
}
```

Comment: I was checking again and again.

Comment: thats really not an issue here. I just edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @jparthj You ask a question. Someone gives a valid answer. Then you change the question, fixing the problem? C'mon that's just plain annoying.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes i understand, but it was a typo. i just did not copy paste the code so typing mistake.

Comment: @glglgl thanks for your effort but i am still having the same issue.

Comment: @jparthj on which line?

Comment: typedef long (*pReaderAddRef)(struct sReader *);

Comment: If you put my code into a file on its own, does it compile? If it does, something is wrong with your file you put it in (maybe a bug in a header file?) If it doesn't, there is something wrong with your compiler.

Comment: yes i tried compiling it, it goes fine. btw this code block is from header file itself.

Comment: @jparthj then something is wrong in the header file above these lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46498/discussion-between-jparthj-and-glglgl)